# Как сделать вот такой вот таймер в картинку?

Tags: php

Дело в том что она генерируется через php. Вопрос как такое реализовать?

[image: Таймер php в картинку]

Comment: Все кто смотрит этот пост с супер крутой картинкой будут взломаны ;) Вместо картинки загружается продвинутый троян с _https://proxy.imgsmail.ru И пока вы любуетесь этим счетчиком, ваши данные утекают от вас.

Comment: Нет не будут взломаны, это по ходу встроено в письмо и к картинке прикреплен мой емаил. Просто при каждом просмотре считает сколько раз я просмотрел картинку. Скорее всего у вас антивирус определяет что картинка запускает скрипт. Из за это выскакиваю сообщения. Я не думаю что goldcoach будут в рассылках троян присылать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто GIFка, которая генерируется при открытии. Проверить можно разобрав её на части.

Вот пример на PHP (*почему вы решили, что mail.ru генерирует его на php?*): [Image only Countdown Clock](http://seanja.com/secret/countdown/) или ссылка на [github](https://gist.github.com/SeanJA/4159063).

Comment: Нет не mail.ru генерирует в php. Mail.ru на все картинки в письме ставит редирект ссылку. Мне пришло на mail.ru почту это письмо. Рассылка от Goldcoach использует этот скрипт.

Answer (score 3):

Я так понимаю, что если сделано на PHP, значит у вас сервер считает время и в любой момент может вывести нужную цифру остатка (на случай если при обновлении страницы нужно подгружать актуальную цифру)?

А дальше всё просто, отдайте первоначальную цифру в JS, и он сделает всё что нужно, есть вот такая либа:
http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

И считает, и выдаёт в любом нужном формате, и имеет событие для окончания времени.

Comment: Ко мне на почту пришло письмо с такой вот картинкой. И меня сразу заинтересовало как они это сделали? Таймер до определенного времени останавливается конечно но перезагрузив страницу идет дальше.